# Can’t import a module within my virtualenv

Tags: python, package

I'm very new to Python and web development. I created a Python project and now I want to import an external library.

I want to import the `apans-client` library, and this is what I’ve done:

1. Download and extract the package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns-client
2. Install the package on the command line:

   ```
   $ cd apns-client-0.2.1  
   $ /Users/myuser/env/bin/python setup.py install
   ```

   The installation runs and seems to complete successfully:

   ```
   running install  
   running bdist_egg  
   running egg_info  
   writing requirements to apns_client.egg-info/requires.txt  
   ..  
   ..  
   ..  
   Installed /Users/myuser/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg
   Finished processing dependencies for apns-client==0.2.1
   ```

   Here `env` is a virtualenv folder where my project is location.

But if I add `import apnsclient` to one of my scripts and try to run it, then I get an error:

```
 No module named apnsclient.
```

What am I missing?

### Update

I use PyCharm, and the Project Interpreter is pointing to a different Python installation:

```
/Library/Framework/Python.framework/3.4/bin/python3
```

I changed the path to `~/env`, but then I got the following error:

> Failed modules
>   Python 2.7.8 virtualenv at `~/env`
>   - Nav
>   generation of skeletons for the modules above will be tried again when the modules
>   are updated or a new version of generator is available.

Comment: Was your virtualenv activated when you installed the package?

Comment: Did you activate the virtualenv `source /Users/myuser/env/binactivate` so that you are running with the right python?

Comment: Dont run `setup.py` manually, use pip instead. Pip usually does a better job at installing packages.

Comment: @user3203010 please look at the update

Comment: @tdelaney i think i didn't run with the right python, please look at the update

Comment: @Mario - i don't use pycharm so I'm not sure how to proceed. I have used the komodo IDE with remote debugging in a virtualenv, if that helps.

Comment: @tdelaney after choosing another interpreter and then re-choosing the ~/env interpreter, the error seems to disappear, i don't know how but it seams to work now.

Comment: @tdelaney just for curiasity what does it mean to activate the virtualenv? why and when do I need to do it? I mean after I installed the virtualenv I also installed python in it, so how could it be that this is not the right python?

Comment: Activating just changes your shell environment variables so that the virtualenv's python is called instead of the system python. For instance, scripts with the python shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top will run your python. `activate` also sets the VIRTUAL_ENV variable, but otherwise its very much like calling /Users/myuser/env/bin/python directly. In fact, setting pycharm to use /Users/myuser/env/bin/python as the interpreter for your project may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use PyCharm, thanks to all the comment I got here I noticed that the Project Interpreter was pointing to a different Python installation than the one in ~/env.

after changing it the issue was fixed.

Comment: Didn't you have the import error with this comment : "ImportError: No module named package1.package1.1.testMethod".

Comment: Almost the same with me, but I'm blocked here... Were you having this?

Answer (score 1):

Activate your virtualenv first, then install apans-client:

```
 $ cd /Users/myuser/env
 $ source bin/activate
 $ cd /path/to/apns-client-0.2.1  
 $ python setup.py install # Activating the virtualenv should ensure correct python is used
```

Comment: Using the virtualenv's python for setup.py should be sufficient without activating first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use PyCharm, so can't really help you there.  But it sounds like by choosing the correct python interpreter, you got it to work.